# Undefined index al mostrar los resultados de una consulta en php, utilizando un count

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, php7

Estoy trabajando en proyecto de un restaurante y tengo una pequeña duda al mostrar los datos de la siguiente consulta.

```
SELECT count(id) FROM `menus` WHERE Data_pedido = '2020-09-09';
```

La traducción de esta consulta utilizando `$smtp` es la siguiente.
[image: Consulta en php]

También tengo un `echo` con resultado que consulta esta mandando respuesta
[image: El error que me esta dando y echo con resultados de sql]

Aquí muestro los datos utilizando php.
[image: Aquí muestro los resultados con php]

La duda la consulta funciona correctamente , pero a la hora mostrar en php me muestra index Unbouned haciendo referencia a que no hay tabla que mostrar y raro porque los datos que me llegan están. Alguien sabe como podría mostrar los datos

Comment: $var_dump($pedidos) que te muestra?

Comment: En la segunda imagen esta el var_dump, y lo que me muestra los resultados del var_dump. Lo raro es que me  undifined index quando en la respuesta de base datos pone el array y associacion

Comment: Y si probas hacer un echo de $Pedidos[0] para ver que te imprime

Comment: Me sale un error, Array to string conversion

Comment: Prueba con los siguiente ya que me parece que es una matriz, $Pedidos['PedidosDiarios'][0]

Comment: Me da el mismo error undifined index

Comment: @AlexCarrasco, la variable `$Pedidos` es un arreglo que contiene otro arreglo, la solución al `notice` es obtener los datos del primer arreglo, ejemplo: `$Pedidos = $Pedidos[0];`, o hacer un `foreach ($Pedidos as $Pedido)` para imprimir la lista de "pedidos"

Comment: Tienes un arreglo dentro de otro arreglo. Haz un foreach de $Pedidos[0]

Comment: Ja funciona muchas gracias a todos